# Database Information : Store it in session or recreate it on every request?

Tags: sql-server, database, web

I have a website that retrieve and display a lot of information from the database. That information can also be the nearly the same between 2 different requests.

I would like to know if it's better to :

1. Store this information in session variables (there can be a lot of information)
2. Recreate it on every request (even if it's nearly the same and can take some time to create)

I'm concerned about scalability when there will be a lot of users.

Any other alternative?

**Trivial Example**

There is a page where you can see a list of every user in the application. On this page there is also a section where you can edit the currently selected user.

When you edit the selected user, you need to post back to the server which will reload the entire page with an updated list of users and the updated selected user information.

Store the user list in the Session or Retrieve it from the database?

Comment: Which database are you using?  In Oracle I'd probably look into tuning the buffer cache and such and letting it handle caching the commonly re-used stuff.

Comment: @Ditto SqlServer. But it's not stuff that is global to the whole application, rather it's specific to 1 particular user on 1 particular request. Meaning that it cannot be shared across the whole application.

Comment: Ok, sorry I'm not that familiar with sql-server, so you'll have to get somebody else to help, however, assuming sql-server has anything similar, tuning how the DB handles memory isn't an issue with regards to you thinking it's only 1 session.  The DB will figure that out. If it's not useful for another session, it won't get used. Perhaps not terribly useful in this situation, so you'll have to see what the sql-server experts suggest ;) good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a general rule for it, this is the kind of optimisation that you decide to do if there are performance problems that you need to address.

In the general case, I wouldn't cache, because caching adds complexity (cache management), and if you want to display the most updated data, you would need to deal with cache invalidation. You could decide to invalidate after a given amount of time, or by setting a flag to refetch from database in the right spots.

Let's say in your example you have the list of users, and your objective is to show the most updated data always, I wouldn't cache it by default. Any modern DBMS (mysql, postgresql, etc...) is probably having a cache system that it's good enough for the general use case.
But let's say you're showing some stats data that needs a query with several joins on tables with thousands of rows. And let's say this data is not going to change significantly in a hourly base, I would definitely cache it.

Keep in mind that premature optimisation is the root of all evil. But in the end, is definitely something that you can answer only yourself, by looking at the problem that you want to resolve.

ps: if you decide to go for caching in session, your best bet is to store PHP Session in memcached (it is an high-performance, distributed memory object caching system). You'll need to install memcached and then modify your php.ini settings, [here](https://www.dotdeb.org/2008/08/25/storing-your-php-sessions-using-memcached/) a quick tutorial for reference.